# Minecraft stops playing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I'm playing minecraft, I have this random freeze, the game doesn't go into not responding, just chat freezes and everybody freezes for a little bit. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Can you still look around? Does your escape menu still work? (Generally these points towards a connection issue) Or does your whole game freeze up, no looking/menus? (This would hint towards it being your PC)

Comment: Does this happen on other servers?

Answer (score 2):

> just chat freezes and everybody freezes for a little bit.

This is most likely caused by the connection between the multiplayer server and your computer. To fix it, you could try:

1. Playing on a different server, possibly located closer to you
2. Stopping any downloads or videos you have in the background
3. Upgrading your Internet connection